# compile QGIS-plugin for Windows: problem with gdal_i.lib version

Tags: qgis-plugins, c++

While compiling my plugin for QGIS 2.2 there are no errors, but it ist still not loading in QGIS because of an dll error. (function not found) I think the problem is at the gdal version. The QGIS-About says it is compiled with GDAL 1.10.1 but my plugin is compiled with GDAL 1.11. So I tried to compile my plugin with referencing the gdal_i.lib form the installed QGIS named "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Valmiera\lib\gdal_i.lib" but cmake says while configuring that it is gdal version 1.11. Why? I tried it with the lib fom QGIS Lisboa - same result. Although the libs have different sizes and dates. Where is the problem?

Comment: are you using the osgeo installer?

Comment: yes, I have installed Lisboa, Dufour and Valmiera as standallone and the sources i got via github and the libs and dlls from osgeo4w

Comment: downloaded sources for qgis 2.4 which is compiled with GDAL 1.11 end everything is fine... just no solution for 2.2